# Is it ok to say 'come out as a winner'?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Grammatically, semantically, there seems to be nothing wrong with it, but Google News finds only several thousand search results. Why? (please, don't ask for context, it's perfectly clear as it is)

Comment: ***only** several thousand search results?* Isn't that enough to convince you the expression is just "normal use of English"? Note that idiomatically it's more common to say [*He came out the winner*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+out+the+winner%2Ccame+out+as+the+winner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccame%20out%20the%20winner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccame%20out%20as%20the%20winner%3B%2Cc0) (without ***as***), but that doesn't imply there's anything *wrong* with the longer form.

Comment: ...oh, by the way - it ***is*** necessary for you to provide context, because in my opinion the exact context can make at least a *slight* difference to whether ***as*** should be included or not. And sometimes a *huge* difference.

Comment: And those are not completely trustworthy news outlets (some of them are not even news media but blogs), like India Today. I'm not being racist, but they are not paragons of English mastery, the Indians. (I googled "came out as a winner", in quotes).

Comment: What do you mean by your obscure second comment? Could you provide a few examples when it makes a difference?

Comment: In some contexts, *to come out **as** a winner* can be a truly "adverbial" usage describing ***how*** someone made their appearance. Maybe *at an award ceremony*, before the as-yet-unknown winner is actually announced (but perhaps there isn't even a "contest"; maybe the subject just presents himself confidently, *like winners do*).That sense would be very unlikely without ***as*** - even more so if we replace ***a** winner* with ***the** winner*, which imho would only ever mean the subject had undergone some selection process *and **was** recognised as being the winner*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer has less to do with the phrase itself (which is perfectly fine as-is), but more to do with your method of verifying the correctness of a phrase.

As you probably know, when Googling something in quotes, only exact matches are returned; slight variants are excluded.

If one phrasing returns less than a dozen hits while another returns thousands, then that might indicate something awkward about a particular wording. Also, we must be careful about putting too much trust in that initial Google search results number, as the number of hits actual hits returned is often much lower than the high number reported on the first page.

This is what my search results on Google News gave:

- came out as a winner (8,850 results initially reported, 68 results actually shown)
- came out as the winner (10,400 results initially reported, 80 results actually shown)
- emerged as a winner (11,400 results initially reported, 80 results actually shown)
- emerged as the winner (34,100 results initially reported, 317 results actually shown)

So, we could say that "emerged as the winner" emerged as the winner. But even that wording isn't orders of magnitude above any of the others.

At least to my native ear, all four variants seem acceptable, particularly in conversational English.

Comment: Does 'come out a winner' sound better to your native ear?

Comment: @SergeyZ - That's completely context dependent. I would have to see two full sentences and know the situation before I could judge which wording sounds better. In news reports, I'd expect to see the past tense more often, unless someone is, say, projecting the outcome of an election, in which case the future might be used: _Polls say she will come out as a winner on Tuesday_.

Answer (score 1):

*Come out as a winner* is fine grammatically, but rarely said by itself - it's rare that you will be commanding someone to "come out as a winner."

Something like this is far more typical:

> You'll come out as a winner if you do this.
>
> All he wanted to do was come out as a winner, and that's why he trained every day.

This phrase also may simply not be extremely common in news headlines, or at least the ones Google tracks.